# Can web server settings override .htaccess file?

Tags: php, download

I have build a website. in that website there is section to download file using php script.
our company has two ISP connections. one ISP allows to dowload file but other blocks it.

i thought this is browser problem but after hit and try methods, i come to conclusion that this is ISP problem. Am i right. please help me out.

Comment: And how does this relate to htaccess?

Comment: My thoughts exactly. The question body is vague.

Comment: If they are offering a programming interface (ie. PHP), there is almost certainly a way around it, but we need to know what is being blocked, and how to be able to be any help. Please edit your question with more info.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it's not the webserver that overrides the .htaccess but the other way around, and some settings indeed may not be allowed to be overridden in htaccess from the server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Some files' extension might be prevented from downloading by the **web server** configuration.